# Precompiled Headers Eigen

Tags: c++, g++, eigen, precompile

I have a simple header file (VectorSpace.h) that includes Eigen library, a vector class, and a member function:

```c++
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <string>

class vector {
public:
  Eigen::Matrix<double,1,Eigen::Dynamic> vec;

double dot(const vector &that){
    return (this->vec).dot(that.vec);
}
};
```

I was trying to precompile this header using g++

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I../userlib/eigen VectorSpace.h
```

which generates a VectorSpace.h.gch, but when I try to compile the main code (which is basically an empty main()):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -include VectorSpace.h code.o -o code
```

I get the following error:

```c++
../userlib/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:56:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type’ {aka ‘__vector(2) double’} [-Wignored-attributes]
../userlib/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, -1, -1, true>, Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, -1, 1, true>, -1, 1, false>, 0>, 0>’:
../userlib/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:41:34:   required from ‘class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, -1, -1, true>, Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, -1, 1, true>, -1, 1, false>, 0> >’
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it because Eigen cannot be precompiled? (I don't have any problem precompiling standard library headers, it's just when I add Eigen that I get the error)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -I../userlib/eigen VectorSpace.h
$ g++ eigen.cpp -I ../userlib/eigen -include VectorSpace.h -H -o eigen
```

where eigen.cpp is the source file containing the main() entry-point.

```
int main()
{
  vector v;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The previous error was solved when I dropped "-std=c++11". Why is that? 
But now, when I use the "-H" flag, it gives me "x VectoSpace.h.gch", so it's not using the precompiled file.

Comment: I had included the -include flag, but gch was sill not being used (I checked again, still x Vectorspace.h.gch) . I wonder if it is working on your system in case you have eigen. What I have is exactly what is written above for VectorSpace.h and eigen.cpp.

Comment: when I removed -std=c++11 , it fails to use the precompiled header, that's why the error changed. The error is there when it is "! Vectorspace.h.gch", so it is using it. I guess I can't precompile eigen

Comment: It would seem you have to set the -std flag when building. If you do -std=c++98 it still works.